# Windows Server 2019 Essentials RAM Limit on ESXi VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2019

How does the 64GB physical RAM limit for Windows Server 2019 Essentials apply when it's run as a virtual machine instance on VMware ESXi?

For example, if I had 128GB of physical RAM on the server in total, while only 32GB is allocated to the Windows Server VM, will there be any issue with licensing or making use of the remaining RAM available to other VMs?

As a follow-up question, since Windows Server 2019 is near the end date of the mainstream support, is it possible or required to "upgrade" it to the LTSC version to continue to have access to support till the extended end date, or no action is needed?

Answer (score 0):

The limit of RAM is only the limit the VM will be able to use. The 2019 Essential cant use more than 64G even if you allocate more to it.

The security update will still be available. The extended support end 2029. If you need to upgrade you will need to purchase an 2022 licence and do an in place upgrade or a migration.